# jQuery .load() callback firing early

Tags: jquery, ajax

I created to following code to retrieve search results via `load()`. The trouble I'm having is that the callback function of the load fires before the ajaxed results are on the DOM. Sometimes the timing seems right, but often it's up to a second early.

```
  // assign area to load content
  var mainContent = $("#ajaxContent");

  // on form change
  $('#facets').change(function(e){

    // serialize form data
    var formData = $("#facets").serialize();

    // fade in loading animation while fade out page
    $('#preload').fadeIn();
    $('.wrap').fadeTo("fast", 0.33);

    // ajax search results, on callback fade out animation, fade in page
    mainContent.load('?' + formData + ' #ajaxContent', function(){
       $('.wrap').fadeTo("fast", 1);
       $('#preload').fadeOut();
    });

    e.preventDefault();
  });
```

Any obvious mistakes? Thanks!

Comment: When you say "before the content loaded in is actually rendered on the screen", do you mean before the content is on the DOM, or before your fade animation is complete?

Comment: Try using the [`.stop()`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) method before the `fade*()` calls.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior I mean before the content is on the dom, $('.wrap') fades back in, showing the old results, followed a moment later by the newly retrieved results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best case here would be to start the ajax request immediately, then showing the preloader. when the ajax is finished, stop fading in the preloader and show the wrap.

```
$('.wrap').fadeTo('fast', 0.33);
$('#preload').fadeIn();
$.get('?' + formData).done(function (html) {
    $('<div>').html(html).find('#ajaxContent').appendTo(mainContent);
}).always(function () {
    $('#preload').stop().fadeOut();
    $('.wrap').stop().fadeTo('fast', 1);
});
```

this results in requesting and showing the content as fast as possible, while still having the  preloader if it takes long enough for it to show.

Guess you could also still use `.load` for this:

```
$('.wrap').fadeTo('fast', 0.33);
$('#preload').fadeIn();
mainContent.load('?' + formData + ' #ajaxContent', function () {
    $('#preload').stop().fadeOut();
    $('.wrap').stop().fadeTo('fast', 1);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want to fadeIn the loading indicator, load the content, then fade it back out. But as you have written, you are starting a fadeIn animation and an asynchronous load at the same time. Which finishes first is anyone's guess.

fadeIn takes a call back to run when the animiation is finished. Trigger your ajax load inside that callback:

```
$('.wrap').fadeTo("fast", 0.33);
$('#preload').fadeIn(function() {

    // ajax search results, on callback fade out animation, fade in page
    mainContent.load('?' + formData + ' #ajaxContent', function(){
       $('.wrap').fadeTo("fast", 1);
       $('#preload').fadeOut();
    });
});
```

This will make things happen in the order you want.

Comment: the only downside to this is it doesn't start the ajax request until the preload is done fading in, resulting in an overall increase in the amount of time between start and finish. If the content has been loaded previously, it's likely that if the server is setup to serve this content in a way that it could be cached, it might not need the preloader at all.